# How do you run a npm command in a electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

Hi there im wondering/trying to run a npm command in order to create a gui interface for a project creation desktop app. Im wondering as i can find any documentation on how to do it if its possible to run a npm command such as yeoman generator command through a electron app.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't what you want simply to spawn a new process?

```
var exec = require("child_process").execFile;

exec("zenity", ["--info"]);
```

So you can also spawn a terminal to do whatever you like in it

```
exec("xterm", ["-e", "yo webapp"])
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html